# Rails array parameter not being passed to Database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to pass an string array, created with [chosen-rails](https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails) through in a `rails 4` form to `mysql`. But, all I'm getting is an empty or null column in mysql. Any suggestions would be great.

How my form looks (more fields in the real one):

```
<%= form_for(@form) do |f| %>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <%= f.label "Cities", class: "input-desc" %><br>

  <div class="clearfix">
    <%= f.grouped_collection_select( :city_name, @state.order(:name), :cities, :name, :name, :name, { prompt: true }, { class: "form-control chosen-select", value: "Select Cities", multiple: true } )  %>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Models:

```
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :city_names
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :city_names, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

Controllers:

```
def create
  @form = Form.new(form_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @form.save
      city_names = params[:city_names]
      format.html { redirect_to form_url, notice: 'Form was successfully sent.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @form }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @form.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

Private
def road_show_form_params
  params.require(:road_show_form).permit(:name, :adress, :phone, :email, :city_names, :comments, :paid)
end
```

SQL:

```
SQL (104.4ms)  INSERT INTO `forms` (`name`, `adress`, `phone`, `email`, `comments`, `paid`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) 
                            VALUES ('Corey Vincent', '', '1234567890', 'test@mail.com', '', 0, '2016-09-23 15:34:29', '2016-09-23 15:34:29')
```

You can see that the SQL insert doesn't even include the `city_name` parameter.

However you can see it's being passed by the form:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"4ttP4U5+LXyrB8nQr2ka7rJqlk6cO+Fk5rCUMA2GWw2+Ww6QFf6DKW55uXVogfMkD0mvz/0QGJmw+42JQkZAZw==",
"form"=>{"paid"=>"false",
"name"=>"Corey Vincent",
"adress"=>"",
"phone"=>"1234567890",
"email"=>"test@mail.com",
"city_name"=>["", "Los Angeles", "Hartford"],
"comments"=>""},
"commit"=>"Submit Vote"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking your `city_name` parameter is getting blocked by strong params.  Typically, you would have something like this when using `nested_attributes`:

```
<%= form_for @form do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :city_names do |ff| %>
    ...
    <%= ff.grouped_collection_select(@state.order(:name), :cities, :name, :name, :name, { prompt: true }, { class: "form-control chosen-select", value: "Select Cities", multiple: true } )  %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Then, in your controller:

```
private

  def road_show_form_params
    params.require(:road_show_form).permit(:name, :adress, :phone, :email, :comments, :paid, city_names_attributes: [:attr_1, :attr_2])
  end
```

`city_names_attributes` should have an array corresponding to columns in the `city_names` table.  When using nested attributes essentially you're letting your `form` object take some parameters for a `city_name` object and pass them on to be saved in your `city_names` table.

Also, if you look at your params you'll see `city_name` and in your `road_show_form_params` you have `city_names` plural. Most likely, you'll have a `unpermitted parameter` in your console output.

This is all assuming your trying to save your `city_names` into their own table.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. Though, all the `city_name` attributes are just city names, so there's really only one attribute, so there wouldn't really be attributes would there?

Comment: You have a relationship `form has_many city_names`, this implies a `city_names` table in the db with `form_id`.  Can you post the relevant  parts of your `schema.rb` ie. the `city_names` table and `forms` table.

Comment: Are you trying to save `city_names` into your `forms` table?

Comment: More or less I just want to get an array of strings(cities), that I can loop through later and get a tally of how many were selected.

Comment: I suppose in that case, if you fix your `road_show_form_params` to include `city_name: []`.  Then in your `form` model have a `serialize :city_name, Array`. You'll probably want to make sure your `city_name` column is `TEXT`.  You can try that, with how you had it originally.